# Issue with checkvob command

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

Before producing the issue, `checkvob` gives the result

```
The VOB's source pools are healthy
```

Now I created some problem in source pool as shown below:

```
cd to some source pool container
[root@Server_Clearcase ~]# cd /net/Server_Clearcase/sdb/ccstg/VOBs/CC_pvob.vbs/s/sdft/2d/3b

replace once file in source pool with another. 
[root@Server_Clearcase 3b]# cp 5-e7f8331f543011e49671000c294d90d1-zr /net/Server_Clearcase/sdb/ccstg/VOBs/CC_pvob.vbs/s/sdft/3c/2c/5-e76832b3543011e49671000c294d90d1-u4
cp: overwrite `/net/Server_Clearcase/sdb/ccstg/VOBs/CC_pvob.vbs/s/sdft/3c/2c/5-e76832b3543011e49671000c294d90d1-u4'? y
[root@Server_Clearcase 3b]#
```

When I run the `checkvob`, it sill says

```
The VOB's source pools are healthy
```

I think it should complain about some issue in source container.

How would you explain that output?

Comment: Please provide a full 'checkvob' command-line

Comment: cleartool checkvob -pool -cleartext -view root_CC.v1 /net/Server_Clearcase/sdb/ccstg/VOBs/CC_pvob.vbs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [checkvob man page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc%2Ftopics%2Fct_checkvob.htm) does mention:

> During check processing, a “healthy” element is one whose containers have:
>
> - the right names,
> - in the right locations,
> - with the right permissions.
>
> **`checkvob`** **does not detect container data corruption**.

That could explain why you see an "healthy" output message.

Try removing one element, and see if the `checkvob` detects the  missing data container.

---

```
cleartool checkvob -pool -cleartext -view root_CC.v1 /net/Server_Clearcase/sdb/ccstg/VOBs/CC_pvob.vbs
```

Note also that a `checkvob` with a `-cleartext` option would limit the analysis to the cleartext pool, skipping the source pool entirely.
Removing that option would make a checkvob processes the VOB's source, derived object (DO), and cleartext pools.

Comment: I understand specifying type of pool checks only for that pool. I checked all the pools and it says "Healthy" status. As per checkvob man page, this is what  expected "checkvob does not detect container data corruption."   But As I intentionally changed a source container, just to produce a case similar to corrupted source container. Now how do I detect such corruption in source container ?

Comment: @user181369 first, you don't use `-cleartext` (or it won't check anything in the source pool). Second, you don't detect corruption by modifying the content, as the doc states.